# VB SQL Server can't convert a picture from my database to a picture box

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have successfully saved my image into my SQL Server database. I can see the image in the datagridview control so I know its there.

But I can't for the life of me convert the byte stream back into an image and display the image into in a `picturebox`.

I have been at this for the past 10 hours and I think I have clicked every link on google and I am unable everything I try doesn't work.

I really want to grab the data straight from the database but I would settle for grabbing the data from the datagridview control. I really wanted to do this in code and was successful in pulling the data using "data source".

I guess where I am really stuck is here. My data in my database is type `image` and I called the column name `Picture`.

```
Dim Command As String = " not sure how to query for a specific row / cell for a byte array")
MY_SQLcommand = new SQLCommand(Command, MY_SQLconnection)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you extract the relevant code your think might be close? It helps with the context and often we can point out something you missing there more easily then showing something new form the ground up.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have so many version I dont know which way is the correct approach.  Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream( put byte array here) <-- I know what to do once I get the byte array from the database.  I am just not sure how to query it correctly.  For example I have one column of pictures and I want a picture from row 5.

Comment: SQL Server? What is the columns actual data type?

Comment: The columns data type is image and its name is Picture

Comment: Also note: `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)